# Google API key is really required?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-places-api

I am using 2 google place APIs in my iPhone app. From beginning I have used it with API keys. But because of over requests that Keys got expired and I cannot fetch the results.
Then I use these APIs with out keys. This is working fine and giving me proper results. I have been using this for last 5 days without any problem.

But I need to confirm that is there any issue or will I face any problem in future if I use with out keys.
I am using like this

```
  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Australia&sensor=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is 2,500 requests/day for free accounts which means without key, and 100,000 requests/day for Maps for Business customers, check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#Limits).

So unless you may exceeds the free daily limit no need to use keys.